# extends/inherit parent component in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, next.js, single-page-application

```
export default function PageTemplate() {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <LeftMenu />

      <div className="content">

        <TopMenu />

        <div id="other-contents">
          // Contents goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <LeftMenu />

      <div className="content">

        <TopMenu />

        <div id="other-contents">
          <h2>I am Index Page<h2/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see most of my contents goes in #other-contents, I will be repeating `PageTemplate` for every page, I wondering if there is way to just re-use `PageTemplate`. Instead of repeating code, I would just do something like extends/inherit/whatever possible and reduce the code in `Index`

I believe this is easier achieved with Class Based Component. But I am wondering if there could function based solution

Answer (score 2):

React prefers [Composition over Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). Use the children prop all react components have.

```
export default function PageTemplate({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <LeftMenu />

      <div className="content">

        <TopMenu />

        <div id="other-contents">
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<PageTemplate>
  // <-- render any content you want here
</PageTemplate>
```

Comment: With this if you are to re-write Index, what will it look like?

Comment: @Paullo Something like this: `<PageTemplate><h2>I am Index Page<h2/></PageTemplate>`?